# Performance Characteristics of Fundamental Operations for Computational Estimation of Algorithmic Complexity

Tags: algorithm, assembly, profiling, compilation, complexity-theory

I've made a compiler for a general-purpose programming language. As part of the toolchain, I'd like to include a profiler with the ability to estimate the time complexity of a given expression. It seems fairly straightforward to calculate the *algorithmic* complexity—that is, assuming all constant-time operations take the same amount of time—but I'd like to be able to approximate the *real* complexity as well. To do that, I need information on the relative performance of individual processor operations such as `inc`, `add`, `mul`, etc., as well as certain higher-level operations such as I/O.

I realise this is both architecture- and implementation-dependent, may yield only fuzzy results at best, *and* is something of a dual question. But does anyone happen to know of any high-quality resources available to get me started? Would looking at open-source implementations of higher-level operations give me enough information to provide a fair estimate of their complexities?

Comment: How is this different from the halting problem?   ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem )

Comment: @cHao: The halting problem asks whether a given program will halt. This asks how long a program that *will* halt *might take* to do so.

Comment: The crux of the problem is that you *can't always know* whether some random program will halt...and you're not going to get an even nearly useful estimate short of actually running the program.  I mean, if you wanna try, go for it.  But people way smarter than you have proven that what you're looking to do is effectively impossible in the general case -- and the general case is exactly what you're going to need to handle.

Comment: @cHao: Setting aside the problem of what constitutes a "random program", the undecideability of the Halting Problem does not mean that we can't determine running times for all or even most programs of interest.  It just means that there exist programs for which this is the case.

Comment: @cHao: See, for instance: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/terminator/

Comment: It also means that someone has to step in and decide which programs to check and which ones not to, lest someone try and check the wrong program and cause the tool to run forever or crash.

Comment: Note that this "Terminator" thing isn't even trying to figure how long a program will run -- it's hard enough to figure out *whether* a program will halt, let alone *when*.  When i see them release a version, i'll reconsider all this -- but the FAQ doesn't inspire confidence at all.

Comment: I second cHao. Note that the Jon_Purdy mentioned that it's "fairly straightforward" to calculate the complexity. I'd like to know how can this be straightforward with loops where conditions change at each iteration! Unless you gonna calculate the elapsed time (i.e. total number of operations), which is an entirely different subject than computing the complexity.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for a good explanation that I now don't have to write. @cHao: It may not be possible to detect, in the general case, whether an application will halt, but I'm not asking about that at all. I'm am asking about the specific case of determining the complexity of a definitely-halting expression. All of this talk about whether or not it's related to the halting problem is only detracting from the original question. I simply want general guidelines for how much more expensive operation A is than operation B, especially in the case that they have the same time complexity.

Comment: I'm willing to go out on a limb and claim that the vast majority of methods/functions in useful programs do not demonstrate the halting problem.  They get, they set, they perform some computations, they do input or output, in fairly straightforward ways.  The main enemy here is not the halting problem, but issues such as the effects of cache -- which make it extremely difficult to make estimates on the level of CPU cycles. I'm not convinced that static analysis can provide useful information, but I do think that someone should try.

Comment: @Rob: Thank you! And that someone might as well be me, but I do need a hand. That's what this and probable future questions are about.

Comment: @Rob: `while (true) { /* stuff */ }` ( an *extremely* common construct) demonstrates it.  You'd need to see under what conditions it'd `break` or `return`, whether those conditions can ever happen, whether they *do* ever happen...and i haven't even mentioned I/O or multithreading yet (both common these days), where a condition could be triggered by something outside the loop entirely!

Comment: Someone could try...and maybe they should.  But they should also know what they're in for, and why no one claims to even *estimate* performance without actually running the program.  it's an undeniably useful thing to know, and a nearly universal question -- "How fast is my code?".  Something every decent programmer in the history of digital computers has wanted to know.  And someone whose software could answer that question would be an instant billionaire.  So one (who's not interested in wasting their time repeating others' mistakes) would ask: why hasn't it been done already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most modern CPUs, the concept of "cycle time for a particular instruction" is not especially helpful.  The pipeline will be handling multiple instructions at once, and they will be competing for various resources inside the CPU - so the performance of a given instruction can only be understood in the context of the surrounding instructions.  And the details will vary significantly, within even the different models in a processor family.

Furthermore, if you're doing anything that is touching data, then cache behaviour is likely to be just as important as instruction execution times.

For x86: have a look at [Agner Fog's "Software optimization resources"](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Answer (score 2):

Intel has some information about their assembly implementation in their articles database. The good ones are pretty dense (like [this](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) 600-page PDF file), but they've got a lot of interesting information, including some tables with approximate latency times. There's also [a table with some latency times for their 64-bit architecture](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/instruction-latencies-in-assembly-code-for-64-bit-intel-architecture/), so you might be able to search for a similar 32-bit one if you want it.

I personally have no idea about any information for AMD's processors. Google might turn up some results, but I haven't used an AMD machine since the Athlon 3000 days, so I haven't had the need to look for this kind of information.

Comment: Ugh. That first one looks very close to what I was looking for. Now if I can just extract the information that I need from the forest of what I don't...

Comment: The tables are *fairly* noticeable if you skim through...but, like I said, definitely dense...

Answer (score 1):

From what I know:
inc: min O(1) max O(log n)
add, sub: O(log n)
mul, div: O(n)

malloc: O(n*m) n is size allocated, m is number of previous allocations.
free: O(1) (sometimes O(log m)).

Comment: As I said, algorithmic complexity is comparatively simple. I'm looking for specific details on which operations of a given algorithmic complexity are faster than which others, in terms of processor cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The group of Reinhard Wilhelm in Saarbrücken does research on [timing analysis](http://rw4.cs.uni-saarland.de/publications.shtml?timing), including cache behavior.